# Why aren't my CSS border colors correct on my HTML table?

Tags: html, css

Here is what my table looks like. Notice the darker border line above the grey colored rows:

[image]

Here is what I WANT it to look like:

[image]

Here's my code. Not the prettiest but it works for the most part. What am I doing wrong when it comes to the borders?:

```css
        .tx {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 0;
          border-color: #dddddd;
        }
        .tx td {
          font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
          font-size: 12px;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 10px 10px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 1px;
          overflow: hidden;
          word-break: normal;
          border-color: #dddddd;
          color: #000;
        }
        .tx .tx-vn4c {
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          border-color: #f9f9f9 #dddddd;
        }
```

```html
<table class="tx">
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-031e" style="width: 120px;">1</th>
      <td class="tx-031e" style="width: 300px;">Swimming</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-vn4c">2</td>
    <td class="tx-vn4c">Running</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-031e">3</td>
    <td class="tx-031e">Shooting</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-vn4c">4</td>
    <td class="tx-vn4c">Diving</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-031e">5</td>
    <td class="tx-031e">Bahhh</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you don't want the borders why do you define them?

Comment: I want a border around the entire table and a line down the middle (see the picture of what it should look like). Is there a simpler way to do that?

Comment: The point is that your CSS rules define borders around table cells. If you want only left and right borders then don't define top and bottom borders (`border-width: 0 1px;`)

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't know you could define them between horizontal and vertical like that. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, @EthanAllen, thats the way it works.  Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp

Comment: Just a side note.  You have miss-matching HTML elements for the `<th>` header elements (they're `<td></th>`).  I'm not sure if that's just a bug in your example or in your actual code.  Looks like it might just be a little copy/paste 'bug'

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-bottom: none;` and `border-top: none;` to `.tx td` class and will fix problem.

```css
        .tx {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 0;
          border-color: #dddddd;
        }
        .tx td {
          font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
          font-size: 12px;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 10px 10px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 1px;
          overflow: hidden;
          word-break: normal;
          border-color: #dddddd;
          color: #000;
          border-bottom:none;
          border-top:none;
        }
        .tx .tx-vn4c {
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          border-color: #f9f9f9 #dddddd;
        }
```

```html
<table class="tx">
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-031e" style="width: 120px;">1</th>
      <td class="tx-031e" style="width: 300px;">Swimming</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-vn4c">2</td>
    <td class="tx-vn4c">Running</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-031e">3</td>
    <td class="tx-031e">Shooting</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-vn4c">4</td>
    <td class="tx-vn4c">Diving</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tx-031e">5</td>
    <td class="tx-031e">Bahhh</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```